# Unable to install RealVNC (debian compatible) in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, realvnc, ubuntu-15.04

I'm trying to install RealVNC in Ubuntu 15.04 while I use command `dpkg -i <realvncinstallerfile>.deb` but I get following errors while installation.

```
Preparing to unpack VNC-Server-5.2.3-Linux-x86.deb ...
Unpacking realvnc-vnc-server (5.2.3.8648) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of realvnc-vnc-server:
 realvnc-vnc-server depends on libc6.
 realvnc-vnc-server depends on libx11-6 | xlibs (>> 4.1.0).
 realvnc-vnc-server depends on libxext6 | xlibs (>> 4.1.0).
 realvnc-vnc-server depends on libxtst6 | xlibs (>> 4.1.0).

dpkg: error processing package realvnc-vnc-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 realvnc-vnc-server
```

I'm unable to connect my PC to the internet to directly download/install VNC as its a production PC. Tried connecting internet via usb dongle but the device supports in windows only. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu somebody kindly help me out with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download all of package's dependencies offline](http://superuser.com/questions/374120/how-to-download-all-of-packages-dependencies-offline).  You need to download the missing packages, as stated in the output you posted (`realvnc-vnc-server depends on...` - you need all of those packages to install RealVNC).

Comment: @Breakthrough Can you please say how to get those packages as I get a number of options in the web which one need to be installed I'm not sure. When I tried 
sudo apt-get install libc6
it says that libc6 is already installed and latest version

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem while installing the RealVNC .deb package on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It was showing me this error.

```
Selecting previously unselected package realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 287754 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack VNC-Viewer-6.20.529-Linux-x86.deb ...
Unpacking realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386 (6.20.529.42646) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386:
 realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386 depends on libc6.
 realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386 depends on libx11-6.
 realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386 depends on libxext6.

dpkg: error processing package realvnc-vnc-viewer:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

However, this command fixed all the broken packages -

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And then I tried `dpkg -i <realvncinstallerfile>.deb` and was able to install successfully.